# keda: Azure Service bus scaled object not scaling deployment-Scaling is not performed because triggers are not active

Tags: azure, kubernetes, keda

Trying to autoscale pod with inbound messages from azure service bus using KEDA. Scaled object defined is

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1  
kind: ScaledObject  
metadata:  
  name: main-router-scaledobject  
  namespace: rehmannazar-camel-dev  
spec:  
  minReplicaCount:  0  
  maxReplicaCount: 10  
  scaleTargetRef: 
name: mainrouter
    kind: Deployment
  triggers:
  - type: azure-servicebus  
    metadata:  
      topicName: topic4test  
      subscriptionName: sub3  
      messageCount: "10"  
      activationMessageCount: "0"  
    authenticationRef:  
      name: trigger-auth-service*
```

with trigger-auth-service defined as

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1  
*kind: TriggerAuthentication  
metadata:  
  name: trigger-auth-service  
spec:  
  secretTargetRef:   
  - parameter: connection  
    name: connectionsecret  
    key: connection*
```

and connectionsecret defines connection string to azure service bus.

```
kubectl describe scaledobject main-router-scaledobject
```

is having status

```
Status:  
  Conditions:  
    Message:  ScaledObject is defined correctly and is ready for scaling  
    Reason:   ScaledObjectReady  
    Status:   True  
    Type:     Ready  
    Message:  Scaling is not performed because triggers are not active  
    Reason:   ScalerNotActive  
    Status:   False  
    Type:     Active  
    Message:  No fallbacks are active on this scaled object  
    Reason:   NoFallbackFound  
    Status:   False  
    Type:     Fallback  
  External Metric Names:  
    s0-azure-servicebus-topic4test  
  Health:  
    s0-azure-servicebus-topic4test:  
      Number Of Failures:  0  
      Status:              Happy  
  Hpa Name:                keda-hpa-main-router-scaledobject  
  Original Replica Count:  1  
  Scale Target GVKR:  
    Group:            apps  
    Kind:             Deployment  
    Resource:         deployments  
    Version:          v1   
  Scale Target Kind:  apps/v1.Deployment  
Events:  
  Type    Reason                      Age                    From             Message
  ----    ------                      ----                   ----           -------     
  Normal  KEDAScaleTargetDeactivated  3m53s (x191 over 98m)  keda-operator    Deactivated apps/v1.Deployment rehmannazar-camel-dev/mainrouter from 1 to 0  


kubectl get ScaledObject main-router-scaledobject  
NAME                       SCALETARGETKIND      SCALETARGETNAME   MIN   MAX   TRIGGERS           AUTHENTICATION         READY   ACTIVE   FALLBACK   AGE  
main-router-scaledobject   apps/v1.Deployment   mainrouter        0     10    azure-servicebus   trigger-auth-service   True    False    False      101m
```

yet pods are not scaled to zero and when posting messages on subscription sub3 pods are not scaled. Pods are also not downscaled to zero when sub3 has no messages. There is always a single pod in running state. Only activity I am observing is pods getting terminated and new pod getting started but pods replicas always remain 1. Is there something I missed in keda configuration?.

Answer (score 0):

KEDA configuration is working . Issue was keda integration with camel-k.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nazar can you please explain how it got fixed i am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @sysadmincrispy I was using KEDA with camel-k which already has  KEDA integrated. For using KEDA with camel-k use KEDA modelines. It worked with Camel without any changes in configuration.